# pdo execute() function not accepting array value

Tags: php, pdo

I was trying to give values dynamically to execute a query.But the value i am giving inside execute() function,its not taking it.Here is the use,

```
$user_id=1;

    if(count($_POST) > 0){
        $date=$_POST['date'];
    }else{
        $date=  "'" . date("Y-m-d") . "'";
    }
     $sth=$pdo->prepare("select goal from daily where user_id=:user_id and goal_date=:goal_date");

            $sth->execute(array(':user_id'=>$user_id,
                                ':goal_date'=>$date ));

            $sth->setFetchMode(PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC);
```

From the above code i am getting empty result.But when i give value directly its giving me a correct value like this,

```
$sth=$pdo->prepare("select goal from daily where user_id=1 and goal_date='2014-05-02'");

        $sth->execute();

        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO :: FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: second one should give you an error, not results

Comment: You shouldn't need to put quotes around the date. PDO will do it for you. Just do `$date = date("Y-m-d");`

Comment: @YourCommonSense Actually second one is fetching me a result.

Comment: yes, edited version does

Comment: @YourCommonSense Now have edited for you.But its working even before.The pdo will give you error only when you give : in your query and not give value in your execute function but not the vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the features of [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is that it quotes your bound parameters for you. According to the docs, when passing an array of bound values to [execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), "All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR". If you want to explicitly specify the data-type of the bound parameter, use either [bindParam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

This means that when you're doing `$date=  "'" . date("Y-m-d") . "'";`, you're essentially causing the string to be quoted twice.

Instead, just do this: `$date = date("Y-m-d");`

Comment: @Does my question  needs negative reputation?

Comment: @prakash I didn't downvote it. Most people won't tell you when they do though (that's kind of the point of anonymous voting), and they also often won't tell you why (although you _are_ encouraged to leave a comment explaining how the question could be improved).

Comment: yeah some people are doing that if they didnt know the answer.Not good.

Comment: +1 unlike a certain someone I know (*who will remain nameless, but he knows who he is*). Good job Patrick. (*Giving praise/credit, where credit is due*) ;-)

Comment: @prakash As Patrick pointed out, using `$date=  "'" . date("Y-m-d") . "'";` shouldn't be done that way. You may have gotten confused when using that type of syntax when using `mysqli` syntax in an INSERT, when using `'" .$var . "'`